# how to bind two data frame with same structure together

Tags: r

I have two df and would like to bind the value from df1 with the value from df2. dfs have same variables and rows. How should I do it?

[image]

```
df1<-structure(list(c1 = 750, c2 = 21, c3 = 65), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df2<- structure(list(c1 = "Student Enrollment", c2 = "Faculty Number", 
    c3 = "Graduated"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data frames that have more than one row:

```r
# create two-row data
df1 <- rbind(df1, df1)
df2 <- rbind(df2, df2)

as_tibble(mapply(paste, df2, df1, SIMPLIFY=F))
```

Comment: Why we need to duplicate df1 and df2 in the first step? If we skipped, then we get new df as 3 obs with 1 var. Why?

Comment: We don't need to, that's just for illustration how it works for a data frame with more than one row. However, as you spotted it didn't actually work correctly for one-row data frames. It does now.

Answer (score 1):

Use `paste`:

```r
d <- paste(df2, df1)
names(d) <- names(df1)
```

```r
                      c1                       c2                       c3 
"Student Enrollment 750"      "Faculty Number 21"           "Graduated 65"
```

Comment: Wow. This is clever!

Answer (score 0):

Using `across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df2 %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_c(., ' ', df1[[cur_column()]])))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  c1                     c2                c3          
  <chr>                  <chr>             <chr>       
1 Student Enrollment 750 Faculty Number 21 Graduated 65
```